# Sql developer How to get Table with Sequence through Sql Export Pump

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In sql developer data pump export i want to export table with it's sequence. Data pump "Export Wizard" how i can work with filter options "Enable Include or Exclude Filter".

Comment: Just one specific table and sequence?

Comment: @mmmmmpie not only this critieria but also i need to know how to apply filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its possible to do this with the SQL Developer tool itself but this is how you would do it via command line:
Created some test objects in a test schema (TEST_EXP_OBJECTS):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_EXP_OBJECTS.TEST_SEQUENCE;
CREATE TABLE TEST_EXP_OBJECTS.TEST_TABLE AS 
SELECT * FROM DBA_USERS WHERE ROWNUM<2;
```

Then created a test directory:

```
SQL> create directory test_exp_dir as '/home/oracle';

Directory created.
```

Then expdp the objects citing the schema, specific table name, and specific sequence name:

```
expdp schemas=TEST_EXP_OBJECTS \
include=sequence:\"= \'TEST_SEQUENCE\'\" \
include=table:\"= \'TEST_TABLE\'\" \
directory=test_exp_dir \
logfile=test.log \
dumpfile=test.dmp
```

Output from expdp:

```
Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Mar 9 08:32:48 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: ***

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Starting "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  /******** AS SYSDBA schemas=TEST_EXP_OBJECTS include=sequence:"= include include=table:"= include directory=test_exp_dir logfile=test.log dumpfile=test.dmp

Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 104 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
. . exported "TEST_EXP_OBJECTS"."TEST_TABLE"             10.82 KB       1 rows
Master table "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SYS.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  /home/oracle/test.dmp
Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Thu Mar 9 08:33:47 2017 elapsed 0 00:00:56
```

Lets create a test schema(REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA), impdp, and verify the data and sequence:

```
oracle@EBS-G2-DB01:/home/oracle> impdp dumpfile=test.dmp logfile=test.log remap_schema=TEST_EXP_OBJECTS:REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA directory=test_exp_dir

Import: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Mar 9 08:39:50 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: / as sysdba

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Master table "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  /******** AS SYSDBA dumpfile=test.dmp logfile=test.log remap_schema=TEST_EXP_OBJECTS:REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA directory=test_exp_dir
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA"."TEST_TABLE"         10.82 KB       1 rows
Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Thu Mar 9 08:39:54 2017 elapsed 0 00:00:01

oracle@EBS-G2-DB01:/home/oracle> !sql
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Mar 9 08:39:57 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select object_name, owner from all_objects where owner='REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA';

OBJECT_NAME                    OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TEST_SEQUENCE                  REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA
TEST_TABLE                     REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA

SQL> select count(*) from REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA.test_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL>
```

And clean up our mess:

```
SQL> drop user REIMPORT_TEST_SCHEMA cascade;

User dropped.

SQL> drop user TEST_EXP_OBJECTS cascade;

User dropped.

SQL> drop directory test_exp_dir;

Directory dropped.
```